# Canonical way to check for integer overflow in usize

Tags: rust, unsigned, integer-overflow, unsigned-integer

I was trying to solve the following [leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-sorted-array/) in Rust:

```rust
impl Solution {
    pub fn merge(nums1: &mut Vec<i32>, m: i32, nums2: &mut Vec<i32>, n: i32) {
        let mut backwards_idx: usize = (m + n - 1) as usize;
        let (m_size, n_size) = (m as usize, n as usize);
        let (mut m_idx, mut n_idx) = ((m-1) as usize, (n-1) as usize);
        while 0 <= m_idx && 0 <= n_idx {
            let (nums1_elem, nums2_elem) = (nums1[m_idx], nums2[n_idx]);
            if nums1_elem <= nums2_elem {
                nums1[backwards_idx] = nums2_elem;
                n_idx = n_idx - 1;
            } else {
                nums1[backwards_idx] = nums1_elem;
                m_idx = m_idx - 1;
            }
            backwards_idx = backwards_idx - 1;
        }
        while 0 <= m_idx {
            nums1[backwards_idx] = nums1[m_idx];
            m_idx = m_idx - 1;
            backwards_idx = backwards_idx - 1;
        }
        while 0 <= n_idx {
            nums1[backwards_idx] = nums2[n_idx];
            n_idx = n_idx - 1;
            backwards_idx = backwards_idx - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

However, this won't work, since `m_size` and `n_size` will overflow when subtracted from 0. I know this isn't canonical Rust, but since the problem is given in `i32`, I can't change it much.

There is the [checked method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52646755/checking-for-integer-overflow-in-rust), but that seems pretty hard to read instead of writing it directly it in the while loop condition. Somehow having the exit condition in the body of the while loop doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: The link you reference is likely justification for the question being a duplicate. But that aside, you can avoid having to do anything tricky or unusual by structuring the logic of your loops differently to avoid the potential for overflow, which may be a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to avoid having to check for overflow is by guaranteeing that your **usize** types, which are only ever being subtracted by 1, are **never 0 to start** in those loops. Refactoring the idx types to be counts, and subtracting by 1 when we want to obtain an index, is one way to do this ...

```rust
impl Solution {
    pub fn merge(nums1: &mut Vec<i32>, m: i32, nums2: &mut Vec<i32>, n: i32) {
        let mut numbers_left: usize = (m + n) as usize;
        let (mut m_left, mut n_left) = (m as usize, n as usize);
        while m_left > 0 && n_left > 0 {
            let (nums1_elem, nums2_elem) = (nums1[m_left-1], nums2[n_left-1]);
            if nums1_elem <= nums2_elem {
                nums1[numbers_left-1] = nums2_elem;
                n_left = n_left - 1;
            } else {
                nums1[numbers_left-1] = nums1_elem;
                m_left = m_left - 1;
            }
            numbers_left = numbers_left - 1;
        }
        while m_left > 0 {
            nums1[numbers_left-1] = nums1[m_left-1];
            m_left = m_left - 1;
            numbers_left = numbers_left - 1;
        }
        while n_idx > 0 {
            nums1[numbers_left-1] = nums2[n_left-1];
            n_left = n_left - 1;
            numbers_left = numbers_left - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to avoid overflow, is to structure the loops differently.... Rust doesn't have the explicit `do-while` syntax, but it does have `loop` which can you can `break` from, and even break out to any number of outer loops using labels.

```rust
    loop {
        nums1[backwards_idx] = nums1[m_idx];
        if m_idx == 0 { break; }
        m_idx -= 1;
        backwards_idx -= 1;
    }
```